# 2 proxy service in ESB WSO2

Tags: web-services, wso2, wso2-esb

I use WSO2 ESB (v4.8.1) and I have to do something like this.
I have two proxy services. One is jms, second is http. First service gets message from a queue and turns a builder to process the message. After that,
 service should send via http this message to second service.

In first service after process message I have:

```
 <outSequence>
     <send>
        <endpoint>
           <http method="post" uri-template="http://localhost:port/services/Two"/>
        </endpoint>
     </send>
  </outSequence>
```

In second service:

```
 <inSequence>
     <log level="custom">
        <property name="serviceTwo" value="Service Two starts...."/>
     </log>
  </inSequence>
```

The problem is, the second proxy service doesn't get this message.
Anybody knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Why are u sending in the outsequence, it should be in the insequence.